# question on group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X$ be any finite set and $G$ be a subgroup of permutations of $X$.
Let $F$ be the complex vector space of complex valued functions defined in $X$.
Consider the action $(g.f) (x) =f(g^{-1}(x))$
Then there is an element $\sigma$ of $F$ such that $g.\sigma=\sigma$ for all $g$ in $G$.
Also $F$ can be written as $H+c(\sigma)$  where $H$ is $G$-invariant subspace.
I got this question from one of my friends. 
Now if $G$ is the whole permutation group of $X$ then I am able to show that there exists a $\sigma$ of $F$ such that $g.\sigma$ . But what is the proof when $G$ is a subgroup of permutation group of $X$?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: there exists $\sigma$ of $F$ such that what? In the 4th sentence from the end.

Comment: All constant functions are invariant.